# MongoDb creating sparse index using c++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, indexing, mongo-cxx-driver

Is there a way to create a [sparse](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-sparse%3atrue) index using the MongoDb (2.2) C++ driver?

It seems that the `ensureIndex` function does not accept this argument. From [MongoDb docs](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_with_commands.html#a9ead4325128f007743900cbb416eade7):

```
bool mongo::DBClientWithCommands::ensureIndex(  
                          const string &    ns,
                          BSONObj   keys,
                          bool  unique = false,
                          const string &    name = "",
                          bool  cache = true,
                          bool  background = false,
                          int   v = -1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up patching the Mongo source code (`mongo/cleint/dbclient.cpp`):

```
bool DBClientWithCommands::ensureIndex( const string &ns , BSONObj keys , bool unique, const string & name , bool cache, bool background, int version, bool sparse ) {
    BSONObjBuilder toSave;
    toSave.append( "ns" , ns );
    toSave.append( "key" , keys );

    string cacheKey(ns);
    cacheKey += "--";

    if ( name != "" ) {
        toSave.append( "name" , name );
        cacheKey += name;
    }
    else {
        string nn = genIndexName( keys );
        toSave.append( "name" , nn );
        cacheKey += nn;
    }

    if( version >= 0 )
        toSave.append("v", version);

    if ( unique )
        toSave.appendBool( "unique", unique );

    if ( sparse )
        toSave.appendBool( "sparse", true );

    if( background )
        toSave.appendBool( "background", true );

    if ( _seenIndexes.count( cacheKey ) )
        return 0;

    if ( cache )
        _seenIndexes.insert( cacheKey );

    insert( Namespace( ns.c_str() ).getSisterNS( "system.indexes"  ).c_str() , toSave.obj() );
    return 1;
}
```

The issue should be [resolved](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7464) in version 2.3.2

Answer (score 2):

For that matter, [`dropDups`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-dropDups%3Atrue) isn't an argument either...

As a workaround, you can build the server command yourself and append the `sparse` argument.  If you follow [this link](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/client/dbclient.cpp#L1078), you'll notice that the server command consists of building a `BSONObject` and the various index options are appended as fields.  It should be straightforward to write your own version of `ensureIndex`.

Comment: It appear that some of the variables used during construction are private and can't be modified outside the class. I ended up patching the C++ driver code.